# Py2exe exceptions SSLError как победить?

Tags: python, python-2.x, telegram

Компилирую простой скрипт на питоне 2.7 в exe с помощью py2exe. При компиляции ошибок нет, при запуске ошибка

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Google знает эту ошибку, насколько я понял из обсуждений, ошибка связана с файлом cacert.pem. Положил его рядом с exe - без изменений. Кто-то решал такую проблему ?
Вот код, который компилирую

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from win32com import client
import telepot
import ConfigParser
import codecs
import os

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.readfp(codecs.open('config.ini', 'r', 'cp1251'))#Задаем имя ini-файла
path = config.get('main', 'path')
chatID = config.get('main', 'chatid')
print (path)
print (chatID)


xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path)
t= books.Worksheets.count  # количество листов
print(t)

ws = books.Worksheets[t-1]
n = ws.name # Имя листа
print (n)
report = 'C:\\test\\'+n+'.pdf'
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, report)
books.Close()
xlApp.Quit()

####telegram
TOKEN = ''
bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
f = open(report, 'rb')  # some file on local disk
n2 = "Отчет "
n2UTF = unicode(n2, 'utf-8', errors='replace')
Text = n2UTF + n
message = bot.sendMessage(chatID,Text)
response = bot.sendDocument(chatID, f)
print(response)
print report
f.close()
os.remove(report)
```

Comment: Убрал `TOKEN` из кода. Не надо так делать!

Comment: Здесь посмотрите [похожий вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726815/requests-exceptions-sslerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory) .